# Is it ok to use 6 as a cost of bcrypt algortihm for 64 chars string?

Tags: php, security, cryptography, unique, bcrypt

What should ideal `$cost` be in this case to prevent brute force attack and even by ***ASIC or an FPGA***

```
$cost = '06';
$secret_key = bin2hex(random_bytes(64);
$store_data = crypt($secret_key), '$2a$.$cost.$'.bin2hex(random_bytes(16)).'$')
```

**Scenerio**

Company give user secret key () which generated by above code (`$secret_key`) to access withdraw some money and this secret key shouldn't never be guessed by hacker.

`$store_data` is string that we stored in our database.

So if attacker get access to database and learn `$store_data` variable he should not be able to access `$secret_key`.

I have used bcrypt algorithm to hash but I am not sure, cost = 6 is secure enough in this case.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why not `password_hash`? 2) `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`'s default cost is 10; shouldn't you at least go with recommended sane defaults? On any reasonable server, a cost of 10 shouldn't be more than 50-70ms.

Comment: 1) I will convert system to Java and I will not be able to find `password_hash` equivalent. @Bytewave

Comment: @Bytewave system will generate 100000 hashed string and it will take too much time. cost 10 is too much in this case

Comment: Don't use BCrypt for this, at any cost.

Answer (score 1):

In 1999, when bcrypt was designed, the cost factors at the time were set so that it takes **at least** 250 ms to calculate a hash.

This was based on the fact that in 1977, on a VAX-11/780, crypt could be evaluated about 3.6 times per second. (i.e. 277 ms per password)

- In 1999, a cost of 6 took 300 ms
- But today a cost factor of 6 is *waaay* too low (4.9 ms)

On my desktop PC:

- **Cost 6:** 4.9 ms
- **Cost 7:** 10.1 ms
- **Cost 8:** 20.8 ms
- **Cost 9:** 41.6 ms
- **Cost 10:** 83.2 ms *<-- current default cost (too low on my PC)*
- **Cost 11:** 166.8 ms
- **Cost 12:** **333.4 ms** *<-- appropriate cost*
- **Cost 13:** 667.9 ms
- **Cost 14:** 1,336.5 ms

Comment: very interesting... but what is we consider 64 cryptographically random byte data. Which cost is fast and secure enough in this case?

Comment: @AlexRobertson Of course a stronger password will take longer to bruteforce. For example, every IT department with moronic password policies (uppercase+lowercase+symbols) will be broken in a few seconds. Meanwhile `blue glass paper alien` will take decades to break. Even better is your random 64-bytes of data. But then that's no longer a password (i.e. it's not something used by any human)

Comment: So in this case what could you suggest as an `cost`? and is it ok to use `sha256`?

Comment: There is a trade-off between performance and security. Above 100ms the delay starts to be noticeable to users. User passwords are generally attacked with frequent password lists such as password lists at [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords). OTOH, if you have 64 random data bytes from a CPRNG or better that is already secure against brute force attacks  but needs to be saved as a hash, any secure cryptographic hash will do, SHA-256 is fine.

Comment: @IanBoyd The difference between 83.2 ms and 333.4 ms is small, about 4x compared to the difference of a single hash of ~1us to 83.2 ms is about 80k. It is the ~80k that is important.

Comment: @AlexRobertson If your users are presenting you with 512-bits of cryptographically random data as a password: you no longer need a password hashing function. E.g. you don't need PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt, argon2. SHA-256 is fine. But are you sure all your users actually have 64-bytes of random data as a password?

Answer (score -1):

You should not use BCrypt *at all* for this, this isn't what BCrypt is for.

BCrypt is for hashing user-created passwords, which might be short, lack entropy, or be reused across many sites. It's not for hashing long securely generated tokens.

Instead of asking how low your cost factor can be, you should just use a fast cryptographically secure hash like SHA256. Paying BCrypt's cost (at *any* cost factor) is completely unnecessary and adds no security.